# How to set the value of a textbox to 0 “Zero” in a continues form footer while the detail of the form has no data MS Access

Tags: footer

I have a continues form in which I used the `if()`, `IsNumeric()`, `isnull` and `SUM()` functions to calculate the total amount of the records if exist in the details, else return me 0 (zero):

```
if(IsNumeric(Tr_Amount), SUM(Tr_Amount), 0)
if(isnull(Tr_Amount), sum(Tr_Amount), 0)
```

However, it is not working fine. While it has no records in in details it doesn't return 0 in the textbox, but it if it has some records it returns the total amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
I used two text box SUM and SUMTotal, sum is invisible

if there is no records then set the text box to 0 else set to sum of records

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
```

If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then`
Me.SUMTotal = 0
Else
Me.SUMTotal = Me.SUM
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

```
if(not isnull(sum(Tr_Amount)), sum(Tr_Amount), 0)
```

what is null at that point is the sum, not the field itself